# How to add unique IDs for aligned sequences of sequential numbers?

Tags: r, data.table, uniqueidentifier

I have a data table of integer coordinates that align between two groups labelled A and B. For example:

```
dt_long <- data.table(LABEL_A = c(rep("A", 20), rep("A", 15), rep ("A", 10), rep ("A", 15), rep ("A", 10)),
             SEQ_A = c(11:30, 61:75, 76:85, 86:100, 110:119),
             LABEL_B= c(rep("C", 20), rep("D", 15), rep("F", 10), rep("G",15), rep("D", 10)),
             SEQ_B = c(1:20, 25:11, 16:25, 15:1, 1:5, 8:12))
```

How can I add an ID column to this data.table with a unique id for each of the continuous aligned sequences? Each aligned sequence needs a separate ID if either SEQ_A or SEQ_B are not sequentially continuous, or if they belong to a different group (ie LABEL). For example:

```
    dt_long_ID <- data.table(LABEL_A = c(rep("A", 20), rep("A", 15), rep ("A", 10), rep ("A", 15), rep ("A", 10)),
             SEQ_A = c(11:30, 61:75, 76:85, 86:100, 110:119),
             LABEL_B= c(rep("C", 20), rep("D", 15), rep("F", 10), rep("G",15), rep("D", 10)),
             SEQ_B = c(1:20, 25:11, 16:25, 15:1, 1:5, 8:12),
                  ID = c(rep(1, 20), rep(2, 15), rep(3, 10), rep(4, 15), rep(5, 5), rep(6, 5) ))
```

Comment: @Gregor I think the OP is interested in whether either "SEQ_A" or "SEQ_B" changes by more than 1 in absolute values. If so, a new ID is created.

Comment: @tmfmnk Seems like `LABEL_A` and `LABEL_B` already are recording that---though not exactly. Rows 20 and 21 have a jump in `SEQ_A` without a change in `LABEL_A`... but there is also a jump in `SEQ_B` and a change in `LABEL_B`.

Comment: @Gregor that is true. Without clarification, it is hard to decide what is the problem exactly.

Comment: Yes, it would be nice if OP would clarify. If `LABEL_A` and `LABEL_B` are irrelevant, they shouldn't be included in the question.

Comment: LABEL_A and LABEL_B are not irrelevant because if either change even if SEQ_A and SEQ_B are continuously sequential it indicates a new unique ID is required. I have updated the dummy dataset.

Answer (score 3):

Updated answer based on the clarified question and the updated data. This will work whether or not the `LABEL` columns are numeric.

```
# helper function for the sequential check
# the & !is.na() just corrects for the first NA value introduced by shift()
foo = function(x) cumsum(abs(x - shift(x)) > 1 & !is.na(shift(x)))

dt_long_ID[, ID2 := .GRP, by = .(rleid(LABEL_A), rleid(LABEL_B), foo(SEQ_A), foo(SEQ_B))]
all(dt_long_ID$ID == dt_long_ID$ID2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: rleid itself will start counting from 1 just like GRP. Also, it can take multiple columns: `dt_long_ID[, all.equal(ID, rleid(LABEL_A, LABEL_B))]`

Comment: Oooh, didn't know `rleid` takes multiple arguments. Very nice!